# Python - Input Error

Tags: python

Please could some one explain me why i get this error :

```
>>> pnome = input('primeiro nome: ')
primeiro nome: Hugo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Hugo' is not defined
```

Im new to Python.

Comment: Use `raw_input` in Python 2.

Comment: Thanks for the help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pnome = raw_input('primeiro nome: ')` Since you are using 2.x python version

Comment: Thanks for the help !!